# Need Maximized windows to overlap the Windows taskbar

Tags: windows-7, windows

I would like the maximized windows overlap the Windows 7 Taskbar.

Notice that I am NOT interested in solutions like auto-hide taskbar or eliminating the taskbar. The taskbar should be there in place but when windows get maximized, they have to cover the whole screen including the taskbar instead of being docked / joined to it.

Comment: Try this program http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/54842-taskbar-always-top-disable-enable.html

Comment: Yes, worked for me. It has some limitations and failures that hopefully are improved in its future versions. Thanks helped me.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Sadly nothing is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I am intermittently having the same problem. It is very annoying whether the taskbar is covered by other windows, or when it obstructs the bottom of windows where status messages and buttons typically live.

I have two remedies for the symptoms, though I have no idea about the cause:

1. Unlock the taskbar and change its height to something different and then back to your preference.
2. Right-click the taskbar and pick properties, select auto-hide and apply, then uncheck auto-hide and press ok.

Both of these trigger Windows to recalculate maximized window size and desktop area and rearrange to suit. I don't know why the initial calculations are wrong though...